# Using toolbar on tag editor raises an unnecessary body length check

Tags: bug, tag-wiki, error-message

If you use any of the toolbar items in the [tag description editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/1) and the body length is not enough to save the edit, you will get an error notification:

> [image: Error raised on toolbar usage]

This notification should not be raised before I made a click on the <kbd>Save</kbd> button.

Comment: What happens here is that clicking a button causes the editor text field to briefly lose focus, and the length check happens upon focus being lost on that field.

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but (a) I don't know how they can fix this. The check happens when you the textarea loses focus; it can't read your mind to know what you're going to press next, and certainly it wouldn't be feasible to code handlers around _every single clickable thing in the toolbar_ to say "oh, it's ok, don't show the check you already showed because they just clicked a button here!" (b) This is easy enough to work around - don't start formatting when you've only typed 6 characters.

Comment: (And I'm pretty sure you've been told this before, but down-voting here does not mean "your post sucks!" It probably means "sure, but this isn't important enough to prioritize.")

Comment: @Stuckat1337 True, but using a tool meant to show the former to express the latter is, in my view, not a great use of the tool, as it means that reports would end up getting suppressed from the home page, and later on automatically removed from the site, just because people considered them too minor to fix.

Comment: @Sonic Careful not to put words in my mouth. I didn't say the post didn't belong here. I said the community here will vote to help prioritize the things that they think are worth fixing, and to not prioritize the things they don't. I think that's the whole point of being able to vote up and down, no? And if there are 500 other fixes with a higher score than this one, and those get prioritized first, I think the system is working perfectly, since they'll never fix them all. If we all cast our one upvote for every bug and nobody ever down-votes, then they're all the same priority. Now what?

Comment: @Sonic Anyway, I'm not saying "this isn't important enough to prioritize." I'm just suggesting -- because the OP asked specifically why people down-voted -- that that's one reason people might have down-voted.

Comment: @Stuckat1337 There is a very easy way to fix this: don’t do the check when the textarea loses focus (what’s the point of that anyway?), but when the user tries to submit the edit.

Comment: @Stuckat1337 Bugs are prioritized by getting more upvotes. It’s not necessary for downvotes to be involved in this.

Comment: @Emil So how else do you disagree with a suggestion that something be fixed? By that logic, shouldn't we also prohibit down-votes across the network? Surely we only need up-votes to push the best answers to the top? Now how do we re-train a decade's worth of culture so that everyone on the network uses down-votes like you do (well, don't)?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Yes, they could change the entire functionality of the page (that was obviously written this way by design, even if you don't agree with the design) to cater to this edge case where someone is formatting content before there's really any content. I thought it would have been implied in my earlier comment that I assumed the overall design and functionality would have been completely overhauled for this edge case; next time I'll be more explicit.